# teamcity 5.1 maven proxy configuration

Tags: maven-2, repository, teamcity

I created a new build configuration and tried to run the same. However I encounter errors saying the artifacts could not be found in the repository. If I run the maven build from command line for the same workspace, the build works well. The proxy configuration has been mentioned in `./m2/settings.xml` and the settings file has been mentioned in the build configuration. I tried even placing the proxy configuration in `TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\maven\conf\settings.xml` but it does not seem to help. Kindly let me know if you have any pointers.

`Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.InvalidPluginException: Unable to build project for plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin': POM 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository[16:59:48]:   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:pom:2.0-beta-7[16:59:48]: from the specified remote repositories:[16:59:48]:   central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)[16:59:48]:  for project org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin[16:59:48]:  at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.checkRequiredMavenVersion(DefaultPluginManager.java:293)[16:59:48]:     at  org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.verifyVersionedPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:205)[16:59:48]:    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.verifyPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:184)[16:59:48]:  at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.loadPluginDescriptor(DefaultPluginManager.java:1642)[16:59:48]:     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.verifyPlugin(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1540)[16:59:48]:  ... 19 more[16:59:48]: Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: POM 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository[16:59:48]:   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:pom:2.0-beta-7[16:59:48]: from the specified remote repositories:[16:59:48]:   central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)[16:59:48]:  for project org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin[16:59:48]:     at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.findModelFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:605)[16:59:48]:  at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:251)[16:59:48]:  at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.checkRequiredMavenVersion(DefaultPluginManager.java:277)[16:59:48]:     ... 23 more[16:59:48]: Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactNotFoundException: Unable to download the artifact from any repository[16:59:48]:   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:pom:2.0-beta-7[16:59:48]: from the specified remote repositories:[16:59:48]:   central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)[16:59:48]:   at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:228)[16:59:48]:  at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:90)[16:59:48]:   at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.findModelFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:558)[16:59:48]:  ... 25 more[16:59:48]: Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.ResourceDoesNotExistException: Unable to download the artifact from any repository[16:59:48]:  at org.apache.maven.artifact.manager.DefaultWagonManager.getArtifact(DefaultWagonManager.java:404)[16:59:48]:   at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)[16:59:48]:  ... 27 more`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `settings.xml` within the Maven installation

e.g. for my TeamCity installation `/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-2.2.1/conf/settings.xml`

Don't forget that TeamCity will probably be running as its own user, so `~/.m2/settings.xml` may not be where you think it is.

Comment: I found a ./m2 folder in c:\ root and tried placing settings.xml but it didn't work. I copied the repository folder my userid's ./m2/ folder and the build works for now. Need to find the real problem though.